System Event Viewer Log - Instead of logging for every moment we are receiving valid time data, can we log only if there is a problem with the time?
Every minute of every day a new line is posted to the System Event Viewer which states the following:
Information: The time provider NtpClient is currently receiving valid time data from time.windows.com
Event ID 37
It is great to know that we are receiving valid time data. But why log this every minute in the System log? This takes up a very large amount of the log, almost all of it.
Instead can I switch the time service only to log if we are NOT receiving valid time data? That would be more helpful and free up space for other important messages. Someone in my field said it was concerning that our server is so adamant about the time being correct and that it was unusual for it to do this. I can not find any similar cases with an explanation for this though.
